# What does Git GUI's "Match Tracking Branches" option do?

Tags: git, settings, git-gui

What does the "Match Tracking Branches" option do in Git GUI?

[image: Match tracking branches option]

I haven't seen any immediate change after enabling the option. I assume it keeps local branches up to date with a repository's tracking branches?

Comment: Nope, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-guimatchTrackingBranch

Comment: @Tieme That explains it. If you add that as an answer I can make it the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From git-config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-guimatchTrackingBranch). (Linked by [Tieme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066637/what-does-git-guis-match-tracking-changes-option-do#comment71745957_42066637))

> Determines if new branches created with [git-gui[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) should default to
>   tracking remote branches with matching names or not. Default: "false".